# How to get multiple children elements of each parent class from multiple parents in selenium?

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

I want to get each child element text from each parent element. How can I achieve this in selenium javascript

```
let driver= new Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();
let searchResult = await (driver.findElements(By.css('.parent')));

for (let e of searchResult) {
//Here I want to get children elements of each parent class
    let title = (await e.getText());
    let body= (await e.getText());
    let footer= (await e.getText());
}
```

Below is the sample html

```
 <div class= "parent 1">
                <div class="title">title1</div>
                <div class="body">body1</div>
                <div class="footer">foter1</div>
            </div>
 <div class= "parent 2">
                <div class="title">title2</div>
                <div class="body">body2</div>
                <div class="footer">foter2</div>
  </div>
 <div class= "parent 3">
                <div class="title">title3</div>
                <div class="body">body3</div>
                <div class="footer">foter3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could directly retrieve each element by it's class:

```
for (let e of searchResult) {
    e.findElement(By.css('.title'))
       .then(t => async{
           title = await t.getText();
       }); 
    ...
}
```

Or you could retrieve all of its children with a wildcard `*`:

```
    e.findElements(By.css('*'))
       .then(children =>{
           ..
       });
```